# SAML: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: SSL peer failed hostname validation for name: null

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, saml

I have integrated SAML 2.0 in my system and I’m using a third-party IDP file like https://login.microsoftonline.com/2ff66663a/federationmetadata/2007-06/federationmetadata.xml?appid=123.

securityContext.xml

```
................
 <bean id="keyManager" class="org.springframework.security.saml.key.JKSKeyManager">
        <constructor-arg value="file:/data/share/work/truststore/samlKeystore.jks"/>
        <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="Web@"/>
        <constructor-arg>
        <map>
               <entry key="test" value="Web@"/>
        </map>
        </constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="test"/>
   </bean>
<bean id="metadata" class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.CachingMetadataManager">
<constructor-arg>
    <list>
       <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadataDelegate">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.HTTPMetadataProvider">
            <constructor-arg>
                <value type="java.lang.String">https://login.microsoftonline.com/2ff66663a/federationmetadata/2007-06/federationmetadata.xml?appid=123</value>
            </constructor-arg>
            <constructor-arg>
                <!-- Timeout for metadata loading in ms -->
                <value type="int">5000</value>
            </constructor-arg>
            <property name="parserPool" ref="parserPool"/>
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadata"/>
    </constructor-arg>
        </bean>
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadataDelegate">
            <constructor-arg>
                <bean class="org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.FilesystemMetadataProvider">
                    <constructor-arg>
                             <value type="java.io.File">WEB-INF/saml/federationmetadata.xml</value>
                       </constructor-arg>
                    <property name="parserPool" ref="parserPool"/>
                </bean>
            </constructor-arg>
            <constructor-arg>
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadata">
                    <property name="local" value="true"/>
                    <property name="securityProfile" value="metaiop"/>
                    <property name="sslSecurityProfile" value="pkix"/>
                    <property name="signMetadata" value="true"/>
                    <property name="signingKey" value="apollo"/>
                    <property name="encryptionKey" value="apollo"/>
                    <property name="requireArtifactResolveSigned" value="false"/>
                    <property name="requireLogoutRequestSigned" value="false"/>
                    <property name="requireLogoutResponseSigned" value="false"/>
                    <property name="idpDiscoveryEnabled" value="false"/>
                    <property name="idpDiscoveryURL" value="http://localhost:8086/saml/discovery"/>
                    <property name="idpDiscoveryResponseURL" value="http://localhost:8086/saml/login?disco=true"/>
                </bean>
            </constructor-arg>
         </bean>
    </list>
</constructor-arg>
 ...................
```

SamlSecurityConfig.Java

```
@ImportResource({"/WEB-INF/securityContext.xml"})
@Configuration
public class SamlSecurityConfig {
    
    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SamlSecurityConfig.class);

    @Autowired
    KeyManager keyManager;

    @Bean
    public TLSProtocolConfigurer tlsProtocolConfigurer() {
        return new TLSProtocolConfigurer();
    }

    @Bean
    public ProtocolSocketFactory socketFactory() {
        return new TLSProtocolSocketFactory(keyManager, null, "allowAll");
    }

    @Bean
    public Protocol socketFactoryProtocol() {
        return new Protocol("https", socketFactory(), 443);
    }

    @Bean
    public MethodInvokingFactoryBean socketFactoryInitialization() {
        MethodInvokingFactoryBean methodInvokingFactoryBean = new MethodInvokingFactoryBean();
        methodInvokingFactoryBean.setTargetClass(Protocol.class);
        methodInvokingFactoryBean.setTargetMethod("registerProtocol");
        Object[] args = { "https", socketFactoryProtocol() };
        methodInvokingFactoryBean.setArguments(args);
        return methodInvokingFactoryBean;
    }

}
```

Exception StackTrace:

> 05:49:30.509 [www.test.com.au-startStop-1] INFO
> o.a.c.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector - I/O exception
> (javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException) caught when processing
> request: SSL peer failed hostname validation for name: null
> 05:49:30.509 [www.test.com.au-startStop-1] INFO
> o.a.c.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector - Retrying request 05:49:30.547
> [www.test.com.au-startStop-1] ERROR
> o.s.s.s.t.MetadataCredentialResolver - PKIX path construction failed
> for untrusted credential:
> [subjectName='CN=stamp2.login.microsoftonline.com,O=Microsoft
> Corporation,L=Redmond,ST=Washington,C=US']: unable to find valid
> certification path to requested target 05:49:30.548
> [www.test.com.au-startStop-1] ERROR o.o.s.m.p.HTTPMetadataProvider -
> Error retrieving metadata from
> https://login.microsoftonline.com/2ff66663a/federationmetadata/2007-06/federationmetadata.xml?appid=123.
> javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: SSL peer failed hostname
> validation for name: null
> at org.opensaml.ws.soap.client.http.TLSProtocolSocketFactory.verifyHostname(TLSProtocolSocketFactory.java:233)
> at org.opensaml.ws.soap.client.http.TLSProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(TLSProtocolSocketFactory.java:194)
> at org.springframework.security.saml.trust.httpclient.TLSProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(TLSProtocolSocketFactory.java:97)
> at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.open(HttpConnection.java:707)
> at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:387)
> at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
> at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
> at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:323)
> at org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.HTTPMetadataProvider.fetchMetadata(HTTPMetadataProvider.java:250)
> at org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.AbstractReloadingMetadataProvider.refresh(AbstractReloadingMetadataProvider.java:255)
> at org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.AbstractReloadingMetadataProvider.doInitialization(AbstractReloadingMetadataProvider.java:236)
> at org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.AbstractMetadataProvider.initialize(AbstractMetadataProvider.java:407)
> at org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadataDelegate.initialize(ExtendedMetadataDelegate.java:167)
> at org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataManager.initializeProvider(MetadataManager.java:437)
> at org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataManager.refreshMetadata(MetadataManager.java:263)
> at org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.CachingMetadataManager.refreshMetadata(CachingMetadataManager.java:86)
> at org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataManager.afterPropertiesSet(MetadataManager.java:167)
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804)
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1741)
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:576)
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498)
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:273)
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1239)
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1166)
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:593)
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90)
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:374)
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1378)
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:575)
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498)
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:846)
> at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:863)
> at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:696)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:662)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:710)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:587)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:526)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:169)
> at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1152)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1097)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:990)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4952)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5266)
> at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:755)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:729)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:695)
> at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1177)
> at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1925)
> at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) 05:49:30.548 [www.test.com.au-startStop-1] INFO
> o.o.s.m.p.AbstractReloadingMetadataProvider - Next refresh cycle for
> metadata provider
> 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/2ff66663a/federationmetadata/2007-06/federationmetadata.xml?appid=123.'
> will occur on '2022-01-20T10:54:30.548Z'
> ('2022-01-20T05:54:30.548-05:00' local time) 05:49:30.548
> [www.test.com.au-startStop-1] ERROR o.o.s.m.p.AbstractMetadataProvider
>
> - Metadata provider failed to properly initialize, fail-fast=true, halting
>   org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.MetadataProviderException:
>   org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.MetadataProviderException: Error
>   retrieving metadata from
>   https://login.microsoftonline.com/2ff66663a/federationmetadata/2007-06/federationmetadata.xml?appid=123.
>   at org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.AbstractReloadingMetadataProvider.refresh(AbstractReloadingMetadataProvider.java:267)
>   at org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.AbstractReloadingMetadataProvider.doInitialization(AbstractReloadingMetadataProvider.java:236)
>   at org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.AbstractMetadataProvider.initialize(AbstractMetadataProvider.java:407)
>   at org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadataDelegate.initialize(ExtendedMetadataDelegate.java:167)
>   at org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataManager.initializeProvider(MetadataManager.java:437)
>   at org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataManager.refreshMetadata(MetadataManager.java:263)
>   at org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.CachingMetadataManager.refreshMetadata(CachingMetadataManager.java:86)
>   at org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataManager.afterPropertiesSet(MetadataManager.java:167)
>   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804)
>   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1741)
>   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:576)
>   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498)
>   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
>   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
>   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
>   at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:273)
>   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1239)
>   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1166)
>   at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:593)
>   at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90)
>   at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:374)
>   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1378)
>   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:575)
>   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498)
>   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
>   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
>   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
>   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:846)
>   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:863)
>   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546)
>   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:696)
>   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:662)
>   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:710)
>   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:587)
>   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:526)
>   at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:169)
>   at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1152)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1097)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:990)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4952)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5266)
>   at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:755)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:729)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:695)
>   at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1177)
>   at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1925)
>   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by: org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.MetadataProviderException: Error
>   retrieving metadata from
>   https://login.microsoftonline.com/2ff66663a/federationmetadata/2007-06/federationmetadata.xml?appid=123.
>   at org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.HTTPMetadataProvider.fetchMetadata(HTTPMetadataProvider.java:274)
>   at org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.AbstractReloadingMetadataProvider.refresh(AbstractReloadingMetadataProvider.java:255)
>   ... 54 common frames omitted Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: SSL peer failed hostname
>   validation for name: null
>   at org.opensaml.ws.soap.client.http.TLSProtocolSocketFactory.verifyHostname(TLSProtocolSocketFactory.java:233)
>   at org.opensaml.ws.soap.client.http.TLSProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(TLSProtocolSocketFactory.java:194)
>   at org.springframework.security.saml.trust.httpclient.TLSProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(TLSProtocolSocketFactory.java:97)
>   at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.open(HttpConnection.java:707)
>   at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:387)
>   at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
>   at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
>   at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:323)
>   at org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.HTTPMetadataProvider.fetchMetadata(HTTPMetadataProvider.java:250)
>   ... 55 common frames omitted

**I tried this solution. but it didn't solve the issue.**

1. I import idp metadata XML file hostname certification to pem file.

   sudo openssl s_client -showcerts -connect login.microsoftonline.com:443 </dev/null 2>/dev/null|openssl x509 -outform PEM > microsoftonline.pem
2. then I import that pem file to samlKeystore jks.

   keytool -import -file /data/tmp_certs/microsoftonline.pem  -alias "microsoftonline" -keystore /data/share/work/truststore/samlKeystore.jks

**Still, I am getting the same stackTrace.**

Comment: The certificate you've captured from openssl s_client points to `CN=graph.windows.net` while the URL is `login.microsoftonline.com`. I guess that this mismatch let fail the hostname verification.

Comment: I checked again and CN is [subjectName='CN=stamp2.login.microsoftonline.com,O=Microsoft Corporation,L=Redmond,ST=Washington,C=US']: unable to find valid certification path to.there is no mismach